# dynamic reference in mongodb not displaying username

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have an application where users can create accounts either local or with twitter and can create posts. I want the users name to be displayed on the post whenever they make one.

So far I have 3 schemas, LocalUser, TwitterUser and Posts. I have looked at mongoose documentation ([mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref)) which allows you to dynamically reference schemas. However, this is not working for me.

models/Post.js

```
const PostsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 postTitle: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
   trim: true,
 },
 user: {
   // Connects user to posts
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   refPath: 'onModel',
 },
 onModel: {
   type: String,
   // required: true -> if I put this I get an error on post
   enum: ['LocalUser', 'TwitterUser'],
 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostsSchema);
```

index.js

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Posts.find()
      .populate('onModel')
      .lean();

    const { user: { username, image, twitterId, googleId } = {} } = req;
    res.render('index', {
      username,
      twitterId,
      googleId,
      image,
      posts,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.render('error/500');
  }
});
```

index.hbs

```
{{onModel.username}} // nothing - Note, twitter schema and local schema both have username
```

I have been looking at multiple solutions and this one looked the most promising. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: `onModel` is the reference for the model name, try `.populate('user')` and access via `user.username`

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for responding. Unfortunately that does not work the username is still blank.

Comment: Are you getting an ObjectID string for `user` by itself? (i.e. without `.username`)

Answer (score 0):

Using the following models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { model, Schema } = mongoose

const postSchema = new Schema({
  postTitle: { type: String, required: true },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    refPath: 'userModel'
  },
  userModel: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['LocalUser', 'TwitterUser']
  }
});

const LocalUser = model('LocalUser', new Schema({ username: String }));
const TwitterUser = model('TwitterUser', new Schema({ username: String }));
const Post = model('Post', postSchema);
```

With this setup/query code:

```
async function go(){
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/so64148230', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })

  const luser = await LocalUser.create({ username: 'luser' })
  await Post.create({ postTitle: 'aluser', userModel: 'LocalUser', user: luser })
  
  const tweeter = await TwitterUser.create({ username: 'tweeter' })
  await Post.create({ postTitle: 'atweeter', userModel: 'TwitterUser', user: tweeter })
  
  console.log('posts', await Post.find({}).select('user').lean())
  console.log('posts populate', await Post.find({}).populate('user').lean())
 
  await mongoose.disconnect()
}

go().catch(console.error)
```

Produces posts with an ObjectID for `user`, which can be populated.

```
posts [
  { _id: 5f769b14aa0c16f83badf411, user: 5f769b14aa0c16f83badf410 },
  { _id: 5f769b14aa0c16f83badf413, user: 5f769b14aa0c16f83badf412 }
]
posts populate [
  {
    _id: 5f769b14aa0c16f83badf411,
    postTitle: 'aluser',
    userModel: 'LocalUser',
    user: { _id: 5f769b14aa0c16f83badf410, username: 'luser', __v: 0 },
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5f769b14aa0c16f83badf413,
    postTitle: 'atweeter',
    userModel: 'TwitterUser',
    user: { _id: 5f769b14aa0c16f83badf412, username: 'tweeter', __v: 0 },
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

From there on the issue is in the template rendering.

Comment: I am getting an `throw new _mongoose.Error.OverwriteModelError(name); OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `LocalUser` model once compiled.` I think whats causing this is because I already have a mongoose model called LocalUser.